# How to parse type names defined during parse

Tags: parsing, typedef, pegjs

I'm using pegjs to define a grammar that allows new types to be defined.  How do I then recognize those types subsequent to their definition?  I have a production that defines the built in types, e.g.

```
BuiltInType
  = "int"
  / "float"
  / "string"
  / TYPE_NAME
```

But what do I do for the last one?  I don't know what possible strings will be type names until they are defined in the source code.

In the traditional way of parsing where there is both a lexer and a parser, the parser would add the type name to a table and the lexer would use this table to determine whether to return TYPE_NAME or IDENTIFIER for a particular token.  But pegjs does not have this separation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right, you cannot (easily) modify pegjs' generated parser on the fly without knowing a lot about its internals. But what you lose from a standard LALR, you gain in interspersing JavaScript code throughout the parser rules themselves.

To accomplish your goal, you'll need to recognize new types (in context) and keep them for use later, as in:

```
{
  // predefined types
  const types = {'int':true, 'float':true, 'string':true}

  // variable storage
  const vars = {}
}

start = statement statement* {
  console.log(JSON.stringify({types:types,vars:vars}, null, 2))
}

statement
  = WS* typedef EOL
  / WS* vardef EOL

typedef "new type definition" // eg. 'define myNewType'
  = 'define' SP+ type:symbol {
    if(types[type]) {
      throw `attempted redefinition of: "${type}"`
    }
    types[type]=true
  }

// And then, when you need to recognize a type, something like:

vardef "variable declaration" // eg: 'let foo:myNewType=10'
  = 'let' SP+ name:symbol COLON type:symbol SP* value:decl_assign? {
   if(!types[type]) {
     throw `unknown type encountered: ${type}`
   }
   vars[name] = { name: name, type:type, value: value }
}

decl_assign "variable declaration assignment"
  = '=' SP* value:number {
    return value
  }

symbol = $( [a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]* )

number = $( ('+' / '-')? [1-9][0-9]* ( '.' [0-9]+ )? )

COLON = ':'
SP = [ \t]
WS = [ \t\n]
EOL = '\n'
```

which, when asked to parse:

```
define fooType
let bar:fooType = 1
```

will print:

```
{
  "types": {
    "int": true,
    "float": true,
    "string": true,
    "fooType": true
  },
  "vars": {
    "bar": {
      "name": "bar",
      "type": "fooType",
      "value": "1"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: If I understand what you are saying, you are basically making types and identifiers the same thing, and relying on context to determine which one you look for?

Comment: Yes. If they appear in the context of a definition, intern them. Then when they occur in other contexts, refer to the interned definition.

Comment: Ok.  Fortunately the language I'm writing the parser for will work this way, although I guess for languages where it won't one would be out of luck